# Is it possible to style this <label> with CSS?

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button

I had multiple issues with JS that changed radio buttons and checkboxes to images and that changed the font of the text on selected radio buttons and checkboxes. I thought I couldn't change the structure of the HTML, so I was looking for workarounds, but after seeing how easy I could fix everything with just CSS, I found a way to change the structure of the HTML, and this simple CSS code fixed everything. Amazing.

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old),
input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label{
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('images/checkbox-blue.png') no-repeat 0 1px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old) + label{
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('images/radio-blue.png') no-repeat 0 1px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label{
  background-position: 0 -18px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked + label{
  background-position: 0 -19px; 
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

My question: is it possible to style radio buttons and checkboxes with this CSS if the input is inside the label, like this?

```
<label> <input></input> Label text </label>
```

The reason I ask is because I have to add a negative left margin on the CSS images so they go over the hidden checkboxes and radio buttons. And when the browser is minimized down to a certain level I have to remove this left margin and add a negative top margin to get the images to line up with the hidden checkboxes and radio buttons.

If I can put the input inside the label, I think it would solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `+` or `~` selector when the label is next to the input box, since there is no previous / parent selector. However you can wrap the text into a span and add style to the span if that helps. Otherwise, you will need to use Javascript.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="checkbox">
<label for="test">Label text</label>

<hr>

<label>
  <input id="test" type="checkbox">
  <span>Label text</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve styling by using font icons, if your site already has any font icon library included. Image background can't be scalable or much customizable.

Check it out this, https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/

Thanks